# Having problems with MapMany implementation. Compiles fine but not a desired output at run-time

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I am trying to test my MapMany implementation but I am having problem getting the output.

The code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{   
    static class E
    {
         static void Main()
        {

            var sequence = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            var result = sequence.MapMany(
            s => s % 2 == 1 ? new int[] { s } : new int[] { });
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", result);
         }


        public static IEnumerable<U> MapMany<T,U> 
        (this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T,IEnumerable<U>> func) {

            foreach (T item in sequence) {
               IEnumerable<U> sequence2 = func(item);

                    foreach (U item2 in sequence2) {
                         yield return item2;
                    }
                }


        }



    }
     }
```

When I try to run the code it gives me with the following output:

```
ConsoleApplication3.E+<MapMany>d__2'2[System.Int32,System.Int32]
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Cheers

Comment: it is doing a result.ToString() which basically outputs the type.  If you want to output values, you need to iterate the values in the result and output each.

Comment: Your method returns a sequence; what are you expecting to see when you `Console.WriteLine` this sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example,

```
result.ToList().ForEach(res=>Console.WriteLine("{0}", res));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Console.WriteLine. The output is correct.

EDIT:
result.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.Write(x + " "));